# Cant have HDR monitor and SDR monitor on at same time

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11, hdr

I Recently bought a HDR capable monitor (electriQ 28" 4K UHD EIQ-284KMB-HDR). I had some difficulty with hdr, but in the end, downloaded VP9 Video Extension to get HDR to work. Since then, when i have HDR enabled on my monitor, my settings are forced to "show only on 1" where 1 is my new 4k monitor. when looking art display settings, my second monitor is tiny, like 1/4th the size of the 1. If i try to change to "extend these displays", either HDR gets turned off, or the 2nd monitor just doesnt turn on. When HDR is turned off and both monitors are on, i cant turn HDR on as it makes the screens flicker then turn back on with HDR still off and games and apps showing no support for HDR.

I have all my drivers up to date both through a 3rd party app and windows update. This is on windows 11

GPU: Rx 550

CPU: i7 9700k

mobo: z390 Gaming Plus

Ram: 3700 MHZ ddr4

I hope this is enough information to help me. I have searched all ovet the internet and it just the stupid things such as restart pc, update drivers, make sure im clicking the right thing etc.

What i personally believe might be the issue is i have downloaded the incorrect codecs or something along those lines.

With HDR:
[image: with hdr]

Without HDR:
[image: without HDR]

Comment: What model is your other monitor? I also don't like using an app for finding driver updates, that usually gets you in trouble.

Comment: @harrymc the other monitor is an Samsung S24E650

Comment: The Samsung is 1K but the electriQ is 4K. It's logical that the first is shown as a quarter of the size of the second. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @harrymc Thats not how that works as its based on the screen dimensions and not resolution. when hdr is off the difference is minimal. The Problem is that i cannot have both monitors on at same time when my 4k has HDR turned on

Comment: Kamil - Screen alignment in Windows is *entirely* based on resolution. Size is totally ignored.

Comment: My bad, false info. Either way, it doesnt fix my issue as its something to do with HDR. i hjave attached images to show what im seeing. (i exaggerated on the difference i see now)

Comment: Have you limited HDR to only the electriQ?

Comment: @harrymc how would i do that? i believe it would do this automatically as i have the 4k screen selected when trying to turn on hdr no? i have also tested this with another screen now. an ASUS VP228 and the outcome is the same.

Comment: Have you tried running your second monitor off the integrated graphics instead of your graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with RX 580. Revert back to 21.8.1 driver version after using display driver Uninstaller in Safe mode. I can't use HDR in extent view on the latest driver, but working without problem on this older one. Hope it helps!